# Updating global variables across modules

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out the best or most pythonic way of updating a global variable across modules. Suppose I have two scripts:

```python
# master.py

import functions as ff
moves = 0

def main():
    update()

def update():
    global moves
    moves = moves + 1
    ff.moves = moves   # send over to ff
    ff.update()
    moves = ff.moves   # get back from ff
```

```python
# functions.py
    
def update():
    global moves
    moves = moves + 1
```

This works but it's a pain to have send and get back from `ff` the updated value of `moves`. Is there a nicer way of doing this? I would prefer to not have to use `__builtins__`.

Comment: Your first sentence contains a contradiction.  There is no Pythonic way to share globals across modules.  You can have a module that has an object with your global state, and import that module/object into all the places that need it, but what you're doing is just bad practice.

Comment: Why not simply change `functions.update` to take `moves` as an argument and return the updated value?

Comment: Why is `moves` defined in `master.py` in the first place? You can update `ff.moves = ff.moves + 1` directly.

Comment: In 99.99% of cases, when you ask about globals, the answer is: Don't use globals. :-P

Comment: @TimRoberts well, we could add it to builtins!!

Comment: @mkrieger1 sometimes the value is updated in master.py and sometimes in functions.py  Doing this to provide students code that runs but they can't see the functions implementation.  They then need to replace the ff.functions with their own.

Comment: @chepner sometimes the value is updated in master.py and sometimes in functions.py Doing this to provide students code that runs but they can't see the functions implementation. They then need to replace the ff.functions with their own

Comment: Shared, mutable globals are a bad design to model for students. If `functions.update` is supposed to mutate something outside of its own scope, it should take an argument that has a method it can call to do so.